# PowerShell logging errors but continue where the error was created

Tags: powershell

Over the last couple of weeks, I've been creating a computer-building script that'll auto restart and auto run on user logon, it's working great but I'm having issues creating an error logging system. Essentially, when an error occurs I want it to append a text document and then carry on where the error occurred. Currently, this is what I have:

```
        $LogOfErrors = Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\LogOfErrors.txt"
    
    If ($LogOfErrors -Contains "True") {Write-Host "The Log Of Errors text document already exists" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Moving On..."}

    Else {

        New-Item  "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\LogOfErrors.txt"
        Write-Host "The Log Errors text document has been created" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Moving On..."
        Write-Host ""}

Try {

#####Computer Build Script Stuff

} 

Catch {Add-Content "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\LogOfErrors.txt" $Error[0] -Append -Force
        SilentlyContinue}

##### End of Script

        $FinishTime = Get-Date

        Write-Host "############################################################################" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "#                                                                          #" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "#      The PC Build is complete, powershell will close in 10 minutes.      #" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "#                                                                          #" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "############################################################################" -ForegroundColor Green

        Write-Host ""
        Write-host "The Script finsihed running at: $FinishTime" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host ""
        Write-host "Please delete the following folder: C:\Scripts" -ForegroundColor Red

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
        Exit
```

The issue I've got is that whenever an error occurs it catches it, writes it to the text document but doesn't go back to where the error occured in the script and carry on running, it'll continue on from the catch and say the script is finished. Any help would be appreticated as I'm completely stuck

I've already got try catches on most of the sections of the script however, these just write that something went wrong don't want these to append the text document, would like when ever any error occurs that it writes it to the text document

Comment: Continuing from where the error was thrown isn't possible when using script-terminating error (i. e. error handling using `try` and `catch`). You'll have to refactor your script to produce non-terminating errors (`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'` or common parameter `-ErrorAction Continue`). Then, to log errors into a separate file, you may [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) the error stream (#2).

Comment: That's really bad practice as it hides all errors by default. I think a good default is to have `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the beginning, so errors won't slip through. Then on a case-by-case basis I might pass `-ErrorAction Continue` to individual commands to turn errors into non-terminating ones (which are still logged) or use `try/catch` to handle errors specifically.

Comment: Thanks Zett42, yeah I know its bad to hide all errors, I think I'm gonna change that now